# How to create class programmatically in owlready2?

Tags: python, owl, owlready

I would like to do the same as

```
with onto:
    class Drug(Thing):
        pass
```

but with having class name

```
className = "Drug"
```

How to do that?

---

I have created ontology with protege, now want it open, add some classes and save back. I am failing in many ways. For examples the code

```
from owlready2 import *
import types

ontology_name = "http://www.semanticweb.org/dimskraft/ontologies/2020/4/my"
file_name = "data/my.owl"
prefix = "file:///home/dimskraft/design/my_ontology/"

onto = get_ontology(prefix + file_name).load()

NewClass = types.new_class("NewClassName", (Thing,), kwds={"namespace": onto})


class Drug(Thing):
    namespace = onto


onto.save(file=file_name, format="rdfxml")
```

gives the following error

```
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'
```

Comment: What exactly do you need? You need a global variable with the name `Drug` to reference the class? This to me seems strange, if you need to map an object to a string, then you should use a map, a `dict`.  Or do you need the `Foo.__name__ == "Drug"`? Can you please elaborate on your situation?

Comment: Did you already had a look at the docs ? https://pythonhosted.org/Owlready2/class.html#creating-classes-dynamically

Comment: @MauriceMeyer here, you could just use `type` directly, `cls = type("Drug", (Thing,), {})` This satisfies `cls.__name__ == "Drug"` "class name" is sort of ambiguous in the question (the variable or the `__name__` attribute). If both matter, it has to be something hacky, like `globals()[className] = type("Drug", (Thing,), {})`

Comment: Arguably the variable is never the name *of* the class, but a name that *refers to* the class. One of the side effects of the `class` statement is to use the name in the statement for both. (I.e., `class` creates both a class named `Drug` and a variable named `Drug` that refers to the class.) This also explains the necessary duplication in `Drug = type("Drug", ...)`; when `type` is called, it has no way of knowing that its return value will be assigned to a variable named `Drug`, so needs the class name provided explicitly.